# Adding new column using existing one using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I want to add new column using existing column in each row of DataFrame , I am trying this in Spark Scala like this ...
df is dataframe containing variable number of column , which can be decided at run time only.

```
// Added new column "docid"
val df_new = appContext.sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema.add("docid", DataTypes.StringType))

 df_new.map(x => {
        import appContext.sparkSession.implicits._
      val allVals = (0 to x.size).map(x.get(_)).toSeq
      val values = allVals ++ allVals.mkString("_") 
      Row.fromSeq(values)
    })
```

But this is giving error is eclipse itself

- Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
- not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$7: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$7.

Please help.

Comment: The `import` should be done outside of the `map`.

Comment: Can you give example of input data and expected output? This should be possible to solve in an more efficient way.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `df.withColumn()` as suggested in werner's answer? That would be the most straightforward solution

Answer (score 1):

`concat_ws` from the [functions object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) can help.

This code adds the `docid` field

```scala
df = df.withColumn("docid", concat_ws("_", df.columns.map(df.col(_)):_*))
```

assuming all columns of `df` are strings.